# Display row by row data by clicking next button

Tags: php

Need to display data from database in different textbox of each value of one row. when I click the next button then show the next row's value in that textbox and when I click the previous button then show the previous row's value.

All code must be in php.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I like the "All code must be in php." part (not)...

Comment: Which introductory college class is this YOUR assignment for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is called pagination.

Searching using "PHP Pagination" in Google gave me these [results](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=php+pagination)

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>    
        <?php        
        function myfunc()
        {        
            $myFile = "testFile.txt";
            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
            $stringData = "Hi there!";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
            fclose($fh);       
        }        
        ?>    
    </head>
    <body>   
        <input type="button" onclick="myfunc()" value="Click!" />    
    </body>
</html>
```